# I have one problem by using springcloud gateway

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-webflux, gateway

**Problem Description**

If I want to use the gateway to forward a request to the authentication centre before forwarding it to the real downstream service, how do I write this code;

**Sample**

I copy the code for NettyRoutingFilter, but response this error;

```
20200110 19:52:08 [reactor-http-nio-1] ERROR org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.error.DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler - Failed to handle request [POST http://localhost:9999/api/upload]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only one connection receive subscriber allowed.
    at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.FluxReceive.startReceiver(FluxReceive.java:276)
    at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.FluxReceive.lambda$subscribe$2(FluxReceive.java:127)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute$$$capture(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:464)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**Environment**

- jdk1.8
- spring-boot 2.0.4
- gateway 2.0.1

Comment: At that point you have to cache the request

Comment: I cached my request by copying the code for  "MutativeDecorator",but Webflux sends HTTP requests asynchronously, so I can't decide whether to send to another authentication center based on the response information of the request.

Comment: Looks like this issue https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/1450

Comment: I have upgraded the gateway to 2.2.1 and can forward the request several times, but I cannot process the response of the intermediate service (maybe the authentication center or other service), so as not to let the gateway forward to the real service (there may be multiple intermediate services).